# Scalaz ReaderT composition

Tags: scala, scalaz

I have 2 function with type of ReaderT and I would like to composite them.

```
def nextTask(): ReaderT[Option, Env, Task]
```

returns an Option of next task to execute

```
def run(taskName: String): ReaderT[Option, Env, Int]
```

gets a task (Task.name) and returns result code or None (failure)

I use ReaderT as environment settings (Test/prod).
Here is a snippet of the test that I made

```
val p = for {
 t <- nextTask()
 c <- run(t.name)
} yield c 
p.run(TestEnv) shouldEqual 1
```

I receive compilation error

```
could not find implicit value for parameter M: scalaz.Bind[Option]
```

What exactly is missing here?

Thanks

Comment: you're missing typeclass for Bind[Option]. Try to `import scalaz.std.option.optionInstance`

Comment: Well it helped. It is so easy. I didn't see it in any documentation.